# Tableau mixing aggregate and non-aggregate IF

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to add a calculated field in my Data Source connection.
If column 'Order Status' is not equal to 'Shipped' then give the sum of the 'Carton Count' else return 0.

This is what I tried and not sure why it won't let me use this.

```
IF([Order Status]) != 'Shipped'
THEN SUM([Carton Count])
ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau doesn't work in a traditional way where we aggregate the the measures in a formula,  tableau doesn't allow you to aggregate in a calculated field instead you take measures as it is and use aggreagation at sheet level.

So your formula will be like:

```
IF([Order Status]) != 'Shipped'
THEN [Carton Count]
ELSE 0
END
```

When you drag this field on to sheet then aggregation is applied automatically